# Create table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a table with two columns, one of the columns should be a date where the date is between 21/07/2013 to today.using sql server 2008r2 and keeping the system date type the same.

Please can someone guide me cause I need to do this ASAP.

Comment: In your loop use the `dateadd()` method to add days to *getdate()* and store this value in your table

Comment: That doesn't answer my question...so when I insert into the columns I should use(a, dateadd()) declare any variables like @start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
DECLARE @currentDate datetime = Convert(datetime, '2013/07/21', 111)

WHILE @currentdate < getdate()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO <your_table>
    (<your_date_column>)
    VALUES
    (@currentDate)

    SET @currentDate = dateadd(dd, 1, @currentDate)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TABLE_CREATION') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE TABLE_CREATION
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE TABLE_CREATION
AS
DECLARE @StartDate date;
DECLARE @i bigint;

SET @StartDate = '2001/01/01'
SET @i=1;

EXECUTE('
        if object_id(''table_name'') is not null
        drop table table_name

        create table table_name (column1_name date, column2_name varchar(max))
        WHILE @StartDate < getdate()
        BEGIN
             insert into table_name (column1_name, column2_name) VALUES (@StartDate,@i)
             SET @i=@i+1;
             SET @currentDate = dateadd(dd, 1, @currentDate)
        END
 ')

 GO

EXEC TABLE_CREATION
```

Comment: Column date is a date range with a start date and an end date of today.

Comment: When you copy my code, you should replace all *@currentDate* variable names with your *@startDate* variable name ;-)